# How to dissect or decode a BTC transaction?

Tags: transactions, network, raw-data, block-header, encoding

I used a packet capture to capture the transaction of bitcoin, and I got the following:

> 16030300040E0000008CC7FC446A010000000000007E000000160303004610000042410425CBD421AACD5F9FB049D168F48D64C57F12C1D98C3D32BAB6A8466C50B12250327DEAA68A7E3F3B1E6CC448AD1C13454528FCB16D64F513510BADA08E89F8A814030300010116030300280000000000000000D1D0C9FA03ED4B75CD0453EC8D55F8B5C79746872CC27A4CC9B95063693CEAF0

By using https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/decodetx/, the data was decoded as below:

```
{
    "addresses": [], 
    "block_height": -1, 
    "block_index": -1, 
    "confirmations": 0, 
    "double_spend": false, 
    "fees": 0, 
    "hash": "d206bcb3b556ab886aca6a55656047b865bb5b06d96f70e34dd4be76d2121f0a", 
    "inputs": [
        {
            "age": 0, 
            "output_index": 2854343883, 
            "prev_hash": "2504414200001046000303160000007e000000000000016a44fcc78c0000000e", 
            "script": "5f9fb049d168f48d64c57f12c1d98c3d32bab6a8466c50b12250327deaa68a7e3f3b1e6cc448ad1c13454528fcb16d64f513510bada08e89f8a814030300010116030300280000000000000000d1d0c9fa03ed4b75cd0453ec8d55f8b5c79746872cc27a4cc9b95063693ceaf0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
            "script_type": "empty", 
            "sequence": 0
        }, 
        {
            "age": 0, 
            "output_index": -1, 
            "script_type": "empty", 
            "sequence": 0
        }, 
        {
            "age": 0, 
            "output_index": -1, 
            "script_type": "empty", 
            "sequence": 0
        }, 
        {
            "age": 0, 
            "output_index": -1, 
            "script_type": "empty", 
            "sequence": 0
        }
    ], 
    "opt_in_rbf": true, 
    "outputs": [], 
    "preference": "low", 
    "received": "2019-04-22T13:12:25.298155786Z", 
    "relayed_by": "3.80.82.172", 
    "size": 380, 
    "total": 0, 
    "ver": 197398, 
    "vin_sz": 4, 
    "vout_sz": 0
}
```

Does anyone know where I can read about how the data gets decoded?

Thanks

Comment: https://btcinformation.org/en/developer-reference#raw-transaction-format maybe? (I found the link from https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/79266/which-serialization-format-the-transactions-use)

Comment: Is that data serialization specific to BlockCypher? Raw transactions generally look like [this](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/glossary/transaction-data) -- The bottom of the page shows decoding. Perhaps the packet you've captured is used for something else?

Comment: you are right. It seems like mine is a little weird. I did a man-in-the-middle on my device and got the network traffic that way. I guess it's encrypted?

Comment: @CarolWard That is a possibility. I believe Blockcypher attempted to make some sense out of it using their arbitrary system, but it's really not valid. The script on the first input is ridiculously invalid and the hash ``d206bcb3b556ab886aca6a55656047b865bb5b06d96f70e34dd4be76d2121f0a`` doesn't appear to exist on either testnet or mainnet.